# Libgdx communication between android module and core module

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, box2d

I am making Libgdx game. My problem is about accessing a class.

1. I have a LevelScreen class in core module.
2. I have a Login class in core module.
3. I have a method in Android module which has a firebase EventListener.

I am using with my onCallBack.

My foots.

1. In Login class I am calling firebase EventListenner
2. If I call LevelScreen class in block body of EventListenner, when the game starts, some assets are mixing.

Hovewer if I call LevelScreen class out of  the block body of EventListenner everything is okey. But this time, I have to touch down 2 times click button. First touching starts EventListenner, second start LevelScreen.

Do you have any idea about using core module's part in android module's part?

I have a Login class in core module.

```
  class LogIn(firebaseInterfaceInCore: FirebaseInterfaceInCore) : BaseScreen() {
        
        ........................................   
         private var firebaseInterfaceInCore: FirebaseInterfaceInCore
            init{this.firebaseInterfaceInCore = firebaseInterfaceInCore }
        
            .............................................
        
        
               override fun initialize() {
                orthographicCamera = OrthographicCamera()
                orthographicCamera.update()
                fitViewport= FitViewport(MyConstants.genislik, MyConstants.yukseklik,orthographicCamera)
                fitViewport.apply()
                   
       
                userNameField.setPosition(130F,1200F)
                userNameField.setSize(700f,100f)
                userNameField.style.cursor
                uiStage.addActor(userNameField)
        
                val sifreField = TextField("Sifre", skin)
                sifreField.setPosition(130F,1100F)
                sifreField.setSize(700f,100f)
                sifreField.style.cursor
                uiStage.addActor(sifreField)
        
        
                val startButton = KontrolTuslari(400f,480f,uiStage,"accept.png")
                startButton.setSize(160f,160f)
                startButton.addListener { e: Event ->
                    val ie = e as InputEvent
                    if (ie.type == InputEvent.Type.touchDown) {
        
                     
        ...........IMPORTANT AREA....................................................
                        firebaseInterfaceInCore.readFirebaseData(object : FirebaseCallback {
                                 
                                  override fun onCallback(result: Boolean) {
                                      when (result) {
                                          true   ->{
                                              BaseGame.setActiveScreen(LevelScreen1())
    //If I call LevelScreen class out of  the block body of FirebaseCallback everything is okey. Bur this time, I have to touch down 2 times click buttun. First touching starts EventListenner, second start LevelScreen.
                                          }                               
                                 }
                                  }
                              })
```

I have a method in Android module which has a firebase EventListenner.I am using with my onCallBack.

```
class FirebaseAndroid : FirebaseInterfaceInCore {
    override fun readFirebaseData(firebaseCallback:FirebaseCallback,kullaniciAdi: String,sifre: String) {
            val database:FirebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            val ref:DatabaseReference=database.getReference().child(kullaniciAdi)
    .
    
            ref.child("KullaniciAdi").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (kullaniciAdi.equals(dataSnapshot.getValue())) {
                        ref.child("Sifre").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                var result:Boolean= false
                                if (sifre.equals(snapshot.getValue())) {
                                    result=true
                                }
                                firebaseCallback.onCallback(result)
                                
                            }
                            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
```

Comment: There's a page about how to do this in the documentation: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: I know this. I did like this wiki decumentation. But only one methot (setActiveScreen) is  problem. I think it is about waitng firebase answer. Mabybe it is about  synchronous or asynchronous or communication between android module and core module, I dont know.

Comment: Why are you using some kind of specialized general listener on your button instead of just a ChangeListener so it can simply react to clicks? Can you show the complete code of the whole listener?